# Prove that there are no positive integer solutions for $a,b,c,d$ if $a^2-b=c^2, b^2-a=d^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that there are no positive integer solutions for $a,b,c,d$ if 
>   $$
> \left\{ 
> \begin{array}{c}
> a^2-b=c^2 \\ 
> b^2-a=d^2
> \end{array}
> \right. 
> $$

This question, in my opinion, is hard and I have been attempting it a lot. Here are my attempts:

I tried to use modular arithmetics to prove that if one of the equations is a square then the other cannot but I couldn't.

I also tried adding up the equations and to somehow get that $x^2<b^2-a<(x+1)^2$ but failed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: suppose $a\geq b>1$. Then $a^2-b>(a-1)^2$.